# navigator.getUserMedia not working in iOS 15, unable to create com.apple.tccd sandbox extension

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, webrtc, p2p

I'm building an IONIC5 based crossplatform application. I’ve a problem with the getUserMedia, only on iOS15, all permission were granted but the video stream is not shown in the video element as srcObject.

I think the problem could be solved if I change the base url in the application, just it's restricted to change from `capactior://localhost` to `http://localhost` or else.

Configuration details: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config

My app log from xcode

````
    App UserMediaPermissionRequestManagerProxy::processUserMediaPermissionValidRequest(B75AA62ED06DE7FB) 158, action: Grant
    App UserMediaPermissionRequestManagerProxy::finishGrantingRequest(B75AA62ED06DE7FB) 158
    App Could not create a 'com.apple.tccd' sandbox extension
    App Unable to create com.apple.tccd sandbox extension
    App 0x15200d618 - [pageProxyID=5, webPageID=6, PID=6669] WebPageP    default    20:49:08.822745+0200    App UserMediaPermissionRequestManagerProxy::processUserMediaPermissionValidRequest(B75AA62ED06DE7FB) 158, action: Grant
    App UserMediaPermissionRequestManagerProxy::grantRequest(B75AA62ED06DE7FB) 158, video: Front Camera, audio: iPhone Microphone
    App UserMediaPermissionRequestManagerProxy::finishGrantingRequest(B75AA62ED06DE7FB) 158
    App Could not create a 'com.apple.tccd' sandbox extension
    App Unable to create com.apple.tccd sandbox extension
    App 0x15200d618 - [pageProxyID=5, webPageID=6, PID=6669] WebPageP```

Thanks! :)
````